# How to only let ONE row expand?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm currently have this list that shows the title on the left and the information on the right of the list and i have a total of 4 columns going ("title"  "info"  "title"  "info"). However I want only ONE row of the info to span from the second column to the fourth column but doing `Grid.Columnspan="3"` on that particular row did not work as it messed up the grid. Any fix for this?

Code:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0"
                  ColumnDefinitions="0.6*,0.7*,0.5*,0.5*">
            <!--Title-->
                <Grid Grid.Column="0"
                      RowDefinitions="0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,1.3*,1.3*">

                        <Label Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="SYMPTOM"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="CONTACT NAME"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="2" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="CONTACT NO"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="3" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="MACHINE NO"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="4" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="SERIAL NO"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="5" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="CUSTOMER NO"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="6" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="VESSEL 1"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="7" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="ADD ADDRESS"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="8" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="NOTE"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="9" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="RECEIVE BY"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="10" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="CONTACT NO"/>

                </Grid>
            <!--info-->
                <Grid Grid.Column="1"
                          RowDefinitions="0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,1.3*,1.3*">

                        <Label Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="HOUSE LEAKING"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="JORDAN"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="2" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="019886933"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="3" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="MACHINE AB"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="4" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="SN0000-002"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="5" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="P02000054"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="6" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="VESSEL NOTE 1"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="7" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text=""/>
                        <!--Span Grid.Row="8" row to the 4th col-->
                        <Label Grid.Row="8" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="THIS IS FOR TESTING MC ONLY"/>

                        <Frame Grid.Row="9"   Style="{StaticResource FrameStyleBlack2}">
                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
                                <OnPlatform.Android>
                                    <customstyle:EntryBorderless Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}" Text="SITI"/>
                                </OnPlatform.Android>
                            </OnPlatform>
                        </Frame>

                        <Frame Grid.Row="10"   Style="{StaticResource FrameStyleBlack2}">
                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
                                <OnPlatform.Android>
                                    <customstyle:EntryBorderless Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}" Text="0163456789"/>
                                </OnPlatform.Android>
                            </OnPlatform>
                        </Frame>
                </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Column="2"
                          RowDefinitions="0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,1.3*,1.3*">
                        <Label Grid.Row="6" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="VESSEL 2"/>
                        <Label Text="CURRENCY SIGN" Grid.Row="9" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                
                    <Grid Grid.Column="3"
                          RowDefinitions="0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,1.3*,1.3*">
                        <Label Grid.Row="6" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="VESSEL NOTE 2"/>
                        
                        <Frame Grid.Row="9"   Style="{StaticResource FrameStyleBlack2}">
                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
                                <OnPlatform.Android>
                                    <customstyle:EntryBorderless Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}" Text="$" />
                                </OnPlatform.Android>
                            </OnPlatform>
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined "a grid inside a grid". The OUTER grid has columns. The INNER grid has rows. Then you tried to make an INNER ROW span COLUMNS. This won't work, because the INNER grid doesn't have columns.

What you want instead is a SINGLE grid, that is two-dimensional (has rows and columns):

```
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="0.6*,0.7*,0.5*,0.5*" RowDefinitions="0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,1.3*,1.3*">
            <!--Title-->
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="SYMPTOM"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="CONTACT NAME"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="CONTACT NO"/>

            <!--info-->
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="HOUSE LEAKING"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="JORDAN"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="019886933"/>
</Grid>
```

Now you can use Grid.ColumnSpan on a single row.

---

NOTE: Given that you are using ColumnSpan, on certain row(s), it MIGHT be sensible to organize the lines of XAML differently. This will have the exact same result, it just may make it easier to see what is happening in each row:

```
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="0.6*,0.7*,0.5*,0.5*" RowDefinitions="0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,0.5*,1.3*,1.3*">
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="SYMPTOM"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="HOUSE LEAKING"/>

    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="CONTACT NAME"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="JORDAN"/>

    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="CONTACT NO"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="019886933"/>
</Grid>
```

Entirely up to you which arrangement makes more sense.

Comment: You were right, it works now. Thank you for this